# Populating combo-box dynamically with mysql table values , using php and javascript

Tags: php, mysql, combobox, dynamic, populate

I want to populate a combo-box on runtime with mysql table values, conditionally, on the basis of a value selected in another combo-box . Can this be implemented by only using PHP, or will i need some client side scripting language such as Javascript?

Please help with code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using javascript and PHP. Your javascript would use AJAX to query a PHP script giving the PHP script the value of the first combo box. The PHP script would then return a list of values that the javascript can then use to populate the second combo box.

You might find it easier to use something like JQuery to make the javascript scripting part easier.

Comment: @sqlchild teaching you all of this could take hours. i am not going to write the code for you. take it step by step and learn how to do it.

Comment: sir, can i you help me out with some reference books/ articles where i could get help for this post?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table looked like this

```
mysql> select * from FRUITS;
+---------+-----------+
| fruitid | fruitname |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Orange    |
|       2 | Apple     |
|       3 | Pear      |
|       4 | Banana    |
+---------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Your code should then look something like this:

```
<?php

 $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','yourUsernameHere','yourPasswordHere');

 mysql_select_db('testdb',$conn);

 $query = "select fruitid,fruitname from FRUITS order by fruitname";

 $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

 $selectbox='<select name=\'fruit\'>';

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $selectbox.='<option value=\"' . $row['fruitid'] . '\">' . $row['fruitname'] . '</option>';
 }

 $selectbox.='</select>';

 mysql_free_result($result);

 echo $selectbox;

?>
```

Comment: he is saying after the page has loaded, when a user selects an option from one combo box, this will decide what a second combo box gets populated with. so you cannot do this in this way during page load with PHP.